# ActionScript 3.0 - get the count of the same value in an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

working in actionscript3 and have an array problem.
I have an array containing numbers, [1,2,3,4,2,1,2,3,4]

how to count number of one value, like the  array. `count function ["4"] //2`

can make an for loop, but like a function for an more easy code.

```
for(var k:uint = 0; k < array.length; k++)
{
    if (array[k] =="4")
    {
        newarray.push(array[k]);
    }

}
trace(array.length);
```

thanks for help!

Comment: If you want to make a `count` function, make sure it takes 2 _function parameters_ (first is target **array** to count from, 2nd is **value** to be counted). The function should **return** an integer of `counted` amount. Learn how to _increment_ a variable (using `++`). Then simply do `if (array[k] == 4) { count++}` to count how many times `4` occurred. I'll check your code if you try something from these suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it is already answered, but still. If you need just the count, the **for..each** loop is faster.

```
function countItems(value:*, list:Array):int
{
    var result:int;

    for each (var aValue:* in list)
        if (aValue == value)
            result++;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: No braces?  For shame!

Comment: @Brian Yep. I always go for the most **compact** and **well-formatted** script possible, for **READABILITY**. Nothing beats **readability** as soon as performance is fine. Have hundreds of classes of 500+ lines in your project - and you'll start to treasure lines too.

Comment: I don't know about READABILITY, but for mundane readability, I actually prefer the braces.  Besides, it's a really cheap bug prevention:  Always brace code!  When you add a line after `result++;`, you guarantee its inclusion in the loop if you have braces; you get a sneaky bug otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list:Array = [1,2,3,4,2,1,2,3,4];
function findInArray(value:*, arr:Array):Array {
    var res:Array = [];
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if(arr[i] === value) res.push(i);
    return res;
}
trace("all indices of 4 in array: ", findInArray(4, list));
trace("total 4s found: ", findInArray(4, list).length);
```

Comment: Asker wants to **count** how many times a value _X_ appears in array. For example if _X_ is `2` then in the posted array you see that `2` was mentioned 3 times. How to get this number 3? is the question...

Comment: wasn't clear until the question got edited, and i'm still not to sure if the asker really only wanted the total count. but anyway i edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
var totalCount:uint = 0;
for(var k:uint = 0; k < array.length; k++)
{
    if (array[k] =="4")
    {
        totalCount++
    }

}
trace(totalCount);
```